# Is there a Framework that recognizes a 3D image and send to a video?

Tags: android, frameworks, augmented-reality

Is there an android Framework that can be used in an app to recognize a 3D image and send the user to a video. This should fall under augmented reality, but so far everything I have viewed uses 2D image and stuff to produce a 3D image on the screen... My situation is backwards from that. I tried using vuforia but I couldn't get the sdk to work, and unity needs an android license. DroidAr doesn't seem to fit the bill either. Or are there any tutorials on this matter? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used the feature, but Metaio has a 3D object, "markerless" tracking feature as well as the ability to do video playback within the SDK. I am sure if you would rather simply redirect to a video (YouTube) or something this would not be exceptionally difficult.

http://www.metaio.com/software/mobile-sdk/features/

Metaio's mobile SDK is similar to Vuforia, so if you had trouble with that you might have difficulty getting it up and running. If your programming skills aren't up to that, you might consider looking into Junaio, an AR browser made by Metaio. With Junaio you simply create a content channel rather than having to build the app from scratch. Again, I have not actually tried this feature yet but the documentation seems to indicate that 3D tracking is available in Juniao:

http://www.junaio.com/develop/quickstart/3d-tracking-and-junaio/

Good luck!